# Scheduling a SQL Job using sp_add_jobschedule

Tags: sql-server

I was trying to add a job using `sp_add_jobschedule`. I was also given a very good link yesterday where I got some clues on how to create a job. While creating the stored procedure I am getting an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Usp_Create_job, Line 19 [Batch Start Line 81]
> Incorrect syntax near ';'.
> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 103
> Could not find stored procedure 'sp_add_jobstep'.
> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 118
> Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.sp_add_jobserver'.
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 127
> Must declare the scalar variable "@Frequency".

I have used the following code to create the Stored Procedure.

```
create procedure Usp_Create_job
as
begin

declare @SP_Name varchar(max) 
declare @JobName varchar(max) 
declare @Step varchar(max)
declare @ScheduleName varchar(max)
declare @Frequency int
declare @Interval int
declare @Time int
declare @StartDate int

EXEC dbo.sp_add_job  
    @job_name = N'@JobName', -- passing job name through input parameter while executing SP Usp_Create_job
    @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]',
    @owner_login_name=N'sa',
    @notify_level_eventlog=0 ;
GO 

EXEC sp_add_jobstep  
    @job_name = N'@JobName',   --passing job name through input parameter while executing SP Usp_Create_job
    @step_id = 1, 
    @step_name = N'@Step',     --passing step name through input parameter while executing SP Usp_Create_job
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',  
    @command = N'

-- actual query
exec @SP_Name',   
    @retry_attempts = 0,  
    @retry_interval = 0,
    @on_success_action = 1,
    @database_name=N'Test' ;
GO  

EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver  
    @job_name = N'@JobName',    --passing job name through input parameter while executing SP Usp_Create_job
    @server_name = N'(local)' ;
GO 

EXEC sp_add_jobschedule 
    @job_name = N'@JobName',
    @name = N'test job schedule', 
    @enabled = 1,   --enabled
    @freq_type = @Frequency, -- on daily basis input value 4
    @freq_interval = @Interval, 
    @freq_subday_type = 1,  -- units between each exec: seconds
    @freq_subday_interval = 0,  -- number of units between each exec
    @active_start_date= @StartDate, 
    @active_end_date=99991231, 
    @schedule_uid=N'8912aa53-ffe9-4f31-b6cb-9a8e2f1ee6e3'

end
```

I have reviewed the code couple of times but was unable to find the exact issue. Any improvements will also be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have mismatched quotes. The highlighting in SSMS should show you this. `@command = N'`

Comment: i have updated the exact error message. pls have a look and also edited the exact code.

Comment: how to fix this.

Comment: Remove the `GO` separators.

Comment: Also, are you creating this procedure in `msdb`? I recommend not doing so, but because you're not, then the procedures *aren't* going to exist, as you aren't using 3 part naming.

Comment: thank @Stu, i have removed the go but got the following message  - The module 'Usp_Create_job' depends on the missing object 'dbo.sp_add_job'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.
The module 'Usp_Create_job' depends on the missing object 'sp_add_jobstep'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.
The module 'Usp_Create_job' depends on the missing object 'dbo.sp_add_jobserver'. The module will still be created; howeve.....'

Comment: `@command = N'exec @SP_Name'` isn't likely to do what you think. The `mvarchar` value `N'exec @SP_Name'` won't have the value of the parameter `@SP_Name` injected into it.

Comment: @CyrusM. again, what database are you creating this procedure in? I doubt (and hope) it's not `msdb`, but then as it isn't, then those objects won't exist in your user database; they are in the `msdb` database.

Comment: @Larnu yes i am creating this in msdb, in my project they asked me to do it, initially created using SQL Server agent then i was told to do it using Stored Procedure. I really had no clue and i tried all possible option and got this far. Please suggest what to do.

Comment: @Larnu it is test environment, sorry my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code.

- You can't have `GO` in the middle of a procedure, it signifies the end of a batch and a procedure must be a single batch.
- The procedures are located in `msdb`, and it seems you want to create the procedure in that database. You need to switch to that database first.
- You haven't defined parameters properly, you have just made local variables.
- You cannot pass parameters contained in quotes, as that just means it will be looked at as a bare string such as `'@SP_Name'`
- Some data types are wrong.
- `@schedule_uid` is an output parameter, you do not need to pass it.
- You are not passing in `@ScheduleName`.
- The value for `@active_end_date` should be in quotes.

```sql
USE msdb;

GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE Usp_Create_job
  @SP_Name sysname
  @JobName sysname,
  @Step sysname,
  @ScheduleName sysname,
  @Frequency int,
  @Interval int,
  @Time int,
  @StartDate int
AS

DECLARE @command nvarchar(max) = @command = N'
-- actual query
exec ' + QUOTENAME(@SP_Name) + '
-- more commands here
'

EXEC sp_add_job  
    @job_name = @JobName, -- passing job name through input parameter while executing SP Usp_Create_job
    @category_name = N'[Uncategorized (Local)]',
    @owner_login_name = N'sa',
    @notify_level_eventlog = 0;

EXEC sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = @JobName,   --passing job name through input parameter while executing SP Usp_Create_job
    @step_id = 1, 
    @step_name = @Step,     --passing step name through input parameter while executing SP Usp_Create_job
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',  
    @command = @command,   
    @retry_attempts = 0,  
    @retry_interval = 0,
    @on_success_action = 1,
    @database_name = N'Test';

EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver
    @job_name = @JobName,    --passing job name through input parameter while executing SP Usp_Create_job
    @server_name = N'(local)' ;

EXEC sp_add_jobschedule 
    @job_name = @JobName,
    @name = @ScheduleName,
    @enabled = 1,   --enabled
    @freq_type = @Frequency, -- on daily basis input value 4
    @freq_interval = @Interval, 
    @freq_subday_type = 1,  -- units between each exec: seconds
    @freq_subday_interval = 0,  -- number of units between each exec
    @active_start_date = @StartDate, 
    @active_end_date = '99991231';

GO
```

Exactly *why* you would want this rather than just using SSMS's nice graphical interface is a different question...